# 1 argument required when initalizing another class in my class

Tags: function, class, flutter, initialization

I want to acces a function from another class. A solution would be to initalize the second class in the class I want to access. Like this:

```
 class Calendarsub extends State<Calendar> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{

 final TableCalendar tableCalendar;

 Calendarsub(this.tableCalendar);
```

When I do this I can acces the functions but the app is not running because the Stateful Widget says: "1 required Argument expected but 0 found."

```
class Calendar extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
  return Calendarsub();  // In this bracket must be the argument
                      // But I don't know which one
   }

  }
```

Comment: In your method `createState()` now you have to return `Calendarsub` and it requires one argument - `TableCalendar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You constructor needs 1 argument - `TableCalendar`

So, you have to initialize it with this value:

```
TableCalendar tableCalendar = TableCalendar(); //or somethimg like that
Calendarsub calendar = Calendarsub(tableCalendar);
```

or make this parameter optional:

```
class Calendarsub extends State<Calendar> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{

 TableCalendar tableCalendar;

 Calendarsub({this.tableCalendar});
```

in second case creating will be like:

```
Calendarsub calendar = Calendarsub(tableCalendar: TableCalendar());
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have two classes using the same name

- Calendar, a subclass of StatefulWidget, which takes a parameter
- Calendar, a State, which doesn't take any parameter

This confuses the compiler. You need to rename so that there's no name conflict anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I edited the code and have forgotten to add the sub.

Comment: @thecode `createState` should return a `Calendarsub` instead of `Calendar`